# さくらインターネットのレンタルサーバで遅延処理後に随時echo内容を画面表示させたい

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

さくらインエーネットのレンタルサーバにて下記のサイトのサンプルを実現したいです。

[[SOLVED] Flush(), ob_flush() not working in PHP (Disabling gzip through htaccess) | Absolutely Tech](http://www.absolutelytech.com/2010/01/31/solved-flush-ob_flush-not-working-in-php-disabling-gzip-through-htaccess/)

```
<?php
include('common.php');
ini_set('output_buffering','on');
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
//ini_set('implicit_flush',1);
ob_implicit_flush();
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
      echo $i;
      echo str_repeat(" ", 500);
      ob_flush();
      flush();
      sleep(1);
}
?>
```

このサンプルで期待される処理結果は、
1秒間隔で 0→01→012→0123→・・・→0123456789 と1桁ずつカウントアップされて表示されていくという動きになります。

このサンプルをさくらレンタルサーバで実行した場合、
10秒間遅延が発生した後、画面に0～9の文字が一気に表示されるという期待とは異なる処理が行われました。

ちなみに、サンプルでは”gzip compression”を無効化する事で実現が可能だという風に示されておりますが、色々調べて、試みたものの、さくらインターネットでgzip compressionを無効化する事ができませんでした。

例えば、.htaccessに

```
SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary
```

と記載してもダメでしたし、他にも以下のサイトに記載されている設定を試してみたのですがダメでした。
[I am not able to disable gzip](http://community.sitepoint.com/t/i-am-not-able-to-disable-gzip/6486)

その他以下のサイトも参考にして、"ob_end_flush()","ob_start('mb_output_handler')"等の対策も試してみましたがうまく行かず。。。
PHPでプログレス表示を行うには？（tp://www.enbridge.jp/blog/2007/08/17232951.php）

また、さくらのレンタルサーバはApacheの設定は変更できないので、Apacheサイドからのアプローチは試みておりません。

なお、ローカル環境（XAMP）では期待した結果が表示されました
（ただ、XAMPはgzip compressionがenableになっているのですが・・・）。

さらに、さくらのVPSでも正常に動作することを確認しました。

どのような設定を行えば前述したサンプルが期待通りに動くのかわからない状態です。。

ご存じの方がおられましたらご教示のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 回答がつかないようなので、質問の改善を提案します。現状、解決したい問題が何なのか読み取りにくく感じます。gzip compression の無効化することなのか、サンプルを動かしたいということなのか、絞った方がいいと思います。後者であれば期待する結果とはなんでしょうか？また、gzip compressionによってサンプルが動かないと読み取れたのですが、もしそうならなぜそう思ったのでしょうか。apache, php の現在の設定がどうなっているか省略せずに記載できないか検討してみてください。

Comment: take88さま、コメントありがとうございます。
ご指摘のとおり、まず、さくらレンタルサーバ上でサンプルを動かせるようにしたいと思っております。
期待する効果としては、
サンプルが期待通りに動いた場合、1秒間隔で
0→01→012→0123→・・・→0123456789
と1桁ずつカウントアップされて表示されていくので、それと同じ動きを実現したいです。
期待する動作が実現できない理由を、gzip compressionの設定だと考えたのは、サンプルの掲載されているサイトでgzip compressionを無効化しようとしていた故、そう考えました。
phpの設定については
gzip compressionがenabledとなっております。
その他にPHPの設定で関連しそうな項目があればご教示ください。
なお、apacheの設定については、さくらレンタルサーバがhttpd.confの設定を確認する事ができないので、どのような設定になっているか不明です。
以上、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。コメントに書かれるより、「編集」を押して、質問の本文に書いてもらったほうが 良いと思います。というのも、質問のタイトルや、質問の本文が分かりにくいので、コメントで補足するより、タイトルや本文を加筆・修正したほうが 回答が集まりやすくなりますよ。

Comment: ob_flushがあるので関係ないかもしれませんがini_set('output_buffering','on');は'off'の方がいいのでは？おそらくファイルタイプかContent-Typeでgzipするかどうか決めているはず。html, css, image以外のMIMEタイプならgzipの対象にならなさそうな期待はあります。

Comment: Kenji Noguchiさま：
アドバイスありがとうございます。提示いただいたoutput_bufferingをoff設定で実行しても結果は同じでした。やはりレンタルサーバでは限界があるのでしょうか・・・

Comment: ウェブアプリケーションファイアウォールとしてSiteGuardと言うのが使えるようですが、これが有効になっている可能性はありませんか？
リバースプロキシ型らしいので、有効になっていればキャッシュされてしまうと思います。
標準では有功でないと思うので違うかもしれませんが、念のため。

Comment: TugrebIcさま：返答がおくれまして申し訳ありません。ご指摘の通り、さくらインターネットのWAFを有効にしておりました。　試しに無効化したところ、期待通りの処理結果となりました。
おかげで対応方法がみつかりました！ありがとうございました。

Comment: コメントで解決した場合の処理がわかりませんが・・・この質問についてはクローズとさせいただきます。

Comment: @TugrebIc だいぶ前の質問ではありますが、よろしければ回答として投稿していただけませんか？

Comment: コメント欄で返信する際は `@ユーザー名` とすると相手に通知が飛ぶのでおすすめです。一応上で声をかけてはみましたが、もしTugreblcさんの方で回答が投稿されないようであれば、ご自身で原因や解決策をまとめて回答を投稿していただいても構いません。いずれにせよ回答左のチェックマークで「解決済み」というマークに、回答の上向き三角で「役に立つ」という投票になります。

Comment: コメントで解決した場合の処理:http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1677/15185

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TugrebIc様の回答で解決できましたので引用させてもらいます。

> ウェブアプリケーションファイアウォールとしてSiteGuardと言うのが使えるようですが、これが有効になっている可能性は‌​ありませんか？ リバースプロキシ型らしいので、有効になっていればキャッシュされてしまうと思います。